# why is this vector multiplication move valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, unitary-matrices

This is dealing with properties of unitary matrices and this is proving that

> eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthonormal.
>
> start with $Ux = \lambda_1 x$ and $Uy = \lambda_2 y$ and take inner products...

$$
x^H y = (Ux)^H(Uy) = (\lambda_1x)^H(\lambda_2 y) = \overline{\lambda_1} \lambda_2 x^Hy
$$

I can follow this up until the last step where I guess we unpack the $(\lambda_1x)^H(\lambda_2y)$ into $x^H \lambda_1^H \lambda_2y$ but then I can't see how we can make a valid move of the vectors and move from the conjugate transpose to just the conjugate

Comment: $\lambda\in\Bbb C$, so $\lambda^H=\overline\lambda$ if you consider it as a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Scalars can be moved freely.

Comment: The quoted claim as it stands is false. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. Unless there’s something you haven’t mentioned that restricts the eigenvectors being considered to unit vectors, you can’t prove the “normal” part of “orthonormal.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ are scalars, not vectors, transpose doesn't "have an effect" on them.

Comment: Oh yeah duh...I forgot lambda was scalar

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda_i\in\Bbb C\implies(\lambda_1 x)^H=\overline{(\lambda_1 x)^T}=\overline{\lambda_1 x^T}=\bar\lambda_1 x^H$.